# How could I make Joomla! fields as a function

Tags: custom-field, fields, com-fields

```
<?php 
  // Turn fields from array numbers into field names.  I usually stick this in the head somewhere.
  foreach($this->item->jcfields as $jcfield){
    $this->item->field[$jcfield->name] = $jcfield;
  }
?>

// Call the field by the name.  With error checking if it is empty.  
<?php
    echo "Value: " . $this->item->field['price']->value;
?>
```

So here I have a field called "price" that is being called by the name.

But say I decide I want to put it in a function instead.  I tried but I'm getting a using $this in non object context.  Here's what I tried:

```
function callFieldByName($fieldName){
    echo "Value: " . $this->item->field[$fieldName]->value;
    }

callFieldByName('price');
```

Seems like a pretty noob question.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're in a template override of com_content.  In which case your $this will point to an instance of a view class, eg. ContentViewArticle or something.

PHP does allow you to declare functions at runtime within objects but $this won't be in scope so you have to pass in a handle of the object. So you can do the following:

```
foreach($this->item->jcfields as $jcfield){
    $this->item->field[$jcfield->name] = $jcfield;
}    

function showField($obj,$name){
    echo (!empty($obj->item->field[$name]->value)) ? "Value: " . $obj->item->field[$name]->value : "";
}

showField($this,'price');
```

Which really seems like it isn't worth it. It's probably easier to just do the work in the foreach loop to prepare for layout. eg.

```
$f = [];
foreach($this->item->jcfields as $jcfield){
    $f[$jcfield->name] = (!empty($jcfield->value)) ? "<br>Value: " . $jcfield->value : "";
}
```